# Using PHP to declare a page url

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project which allows me to create a customer database. I have made an Create.php and Delete.php but am having issues with the basic structure for an Edit page.

My initial idea is to create a populated drop down box (Which I can do) which on click will take the user to domain.com/Customer.php?Customer_name="JohnD"

I am having a few issues with regards to this as it is doing 2 things.

1. It is printing out ALL of the data in my table into the echo.
2. It isn't taking the values from the URL, However I know that I have missed something but am unsure of what I need to search for.

Here is my snippet so far:

```
               <h2>
                <?Php
                $sql="SELECT id,customer_name FROM Customers";
                $result =mysql_query($sql);
                while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                ?>
                <?Php echo $data['customer_name']; } ?>
                </h2>
```

As of yet I am getting this in the header:

John Doe Jimmy Timmy Test

These are all the values inside my rows for the table Customers.

Sorry if the question seems all over the place. I will correct if it is not easy to understand.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: After reading all the posts I realised what I was doing wrong. Part of it was to do with my id's being a weird number in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this url

```
domain.com/Customer.php?CID=1
```

and the code should look like

```
<?php

            $customer_id = (int) $_GET['CID'];

            $query = "SELECT id, customer_name FROM Customers 
                           WHERE id = {$customer_id}";

            $result = mysql_query($query) or die('<p>' . $query . '</p><div>' . 
                                   mysql_error() . '</div>');

            $customer = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);  

?>
 <h2><?php echo $customer['customer_name'] ?></h2>
```

Comment: I assume WHERE id = {customer_id}"; Would be what I have the id for customers in my MYSQL is.

So 

ID     Customer_name     Address

etc?

Comment: yes, you can use name, address or any other info to search record. using id means that you are searching the specified record and don't want any other record. Option like, keyword base search, is used when you are not sure about what you are looking for. if you list records at previous page and link  the page to show the specified record detail, always use the id. i used the mysql function because this guy looks new comer to me, and may not be aware of PDO so i solved his problem in the code that he might know well.. does it makes sense?

Comment: Thanks fkabeer, It did help. I think I'm going to stick to ID though now rather than ?name=

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$_GET` to get the parameters from the URL.

```
<?php

  //customer.php?Customer_name=JohnD (no quotes)

  echo $_GET[Customer_name];

?>
```

You would then use `mysqli_` or `PDO` to bind `$_GET[Customer_name]` and execute the query. If you don't bind parameters in your SQL query, you will be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Hello, I didn't know PHP has gotten rid of that. Thanks. 

Sorry if this sounds confusing but I am still trying to understand the method behind this. 
On my populated dropdown page (Customerselect.php) I would have it link to "Customer.php?Customer_Name=" . $_GET[Customer_name]; 

Is that correct? 

I am reading into mysqli now to make changes.

Comment: You should use an ID. If you're using a drop down, you would have the customer id as an option.

Answer (score 1):

You need to restrict the SQL select to the specific customer with a  where clause. And you may be getting that customer id from the request. I would suggest that you use customer id rather than name in the drop down box. That way the URL will be:

```
  domain.com/Customer.php?id=1
```

On the Customer.php page you can get the value using `$id = $_GET['id'];`

Now as for your SQL you should use some safer method for querying the database say:

```
   $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb';
   $username = 'myun';
   $password = 'mypw';
   $options = array(
       PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
   ); 
   $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
   $stmt = $dbh->prepare("select id, Customer_name from customers where id = :id");
   $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
   $stmt->execute();

   while($c = $stmt->fetch()){
          echo $c['customer_name'];
   }
```

This way only data for the selected customer will be displayed.